# unexpected typescript compiler behavior when using a function interface with void

Tags: typescript, interface

If I define a function interface with return type as number, the complier will warn me

```js
interface RequestHandler {
    (): number
}

// the compiler will prompt an error
// because " Type '() => boolean' is not assignable to type 'RequestHandler'" 
const handler: RequestHandler = function (): boolean {
    return false
}
```

**However, if I do this, the compiler seems ok with it**

```js
interface RequestHandler {
    (): void
}

const handler: RequestHandler = function (): boolean {
    return false
}
```

At first, my guess was that a funtion with void return type will accept any return type, which is wrong according to this:

```js
// error TS2322: Type 'boolean' is not assignable to type 'void'
function foo(): void {
    return true
}
```

Guess my assumption is not valid, can anyone explain such behavior?

---

**Edit**
ABOS's answer inspired me to find more about this behavior
I will put up a new code piece as a demonstration

```js
class Animal {
    eat() {}
}

// Dog is a subtype of Animal
class Dog extends Animal {
    bark() {}
}

interface AnimalBuilder {
    (): Animal
}

interface DogBuilder {
    (): Dog
}
// DogBuilder is a subtype of Animal Builder

declare let animalBuilder: AnimalBuilder
declare let dogBuilder: DogBuilder

// this demonstrate "co-variance"
animalBuilder = dogBuilder // Ok
dogBuilder = animalBuilder // Error

interface AnimalFeeder {
    (animal: Animal): void
}

interface DogFeeder {
    (dog: Dog): void
}
// ...while AnimalFeeder is a subtype of DogFeeder (under "strictFunctionTypes")
// this is called "contra-variance"
// Although counter-intuitive at first glance, it ensures stronger type safety 


declare let animalFeeder: AnimalFeeder
declare let dogFeeder: DogFeeder

// "contravariance"
dogFeeder = animalFeeder // Ok
animalFeeder = dogFeeder // Error when "--strictFunctionTypes"
// Ok when "strictFunctionTypes" is set to false, bi-variance
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My understanding: there are two different **Type Compatibility** checks.

For

```
const handler: RequestHandler = function (): boolean {
    return false
}
```

What happens here is a function of return type boolean is assignable to void, according to [Comparing two functions](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/type-compatibility.html#comparing-two-functions). Note the example at the bottom of this section and the statement "The type system enforces that the source function’s return type be a subtype of the target type’s return type." In the case here, void is a subtype of boolean.

For

```
// error TS2322: Type 'boolean' is not assignable to type 'void'
function foo(): void {
    return true
}
```

What happens here is data type comparison, unlike the first case. So it complains about mismatched types as expected.

Comment: Do you mean boolean is a subtype of void?

Comment: the example is :
let x = () => ({ name: "Alice" });
let y = () => ({ name: "Alice", location: "Seattle" });

x = y; // OK

Comment: I get it now. Thanks for the answer. Although I do believe "() => boolean" is considered as a subtype of "() => void"